# Expected value of position of the first $i$ where $X_i$ is greater than $X_0$

Tags: probability, expected-value

Say there's an infinite list of numbers drawn uniformly from $[0,100]$. Let's call the first number in this list $X_0$, and the $i^\text{th}$ number $X_i$. What's the expected value of $i$, where $i$ is the first number where $X_i > X_0$?

**Here's how I've approached this problem; where am I wrong?**

All numbers after $X_0$ have a $\frac{1}{2}$ chance of being larger or smaller than $X_0$. Therefore, we can model this as an infinite series, where $X_1$ happens to be the first number larger than $X_0$ with probability $\frac{1}{2}$, $X_2$ happens to be the first number larger than $X_0$ with probability $\left(\frac{1}{2}\right)^2$, $X_3$ with probability $\left(\frac{1}{2}\right)^3$, etc...

This results in the following series:

$$ \frac{1}{2}\cdot 1 + \frac{1}{4}\cdot 2 + \frac{1}{8}\cdot 3 \dotsb = 2$$

Comment: It is not true that each choice has a $\frac 12$ chance of being larger than $x_0$,.  If, say, $x_0=100$ then that probability is $0$, for example.

Comment: To b e clear:  is your distribution continuous or discrete?  That is, can $x_i$ take on any real value (in the range) or only integer values?

Comment: continuous! But, in expectation, we'd expect X_0 to be 50, right?

Comment: That is true, but irrelevant.  If $x_0=99.99999$ then it will take a great many trials to see a greater value.  In the discrete case, the expected number is infinite (since no number of trials will get you a number greater than $100$).  In the continuous case you will get an integral which, a priori, could diverge.

Comment: @lulu It seems that you and OP are talking past each other. You seem to be working under the assumption that $X_0$ is fixed (or rather that we are working under the conditional distribution given $X_0=x_0$), whereas OP considers $X_0$ as random. Of course $P(X_1 > X_0) = \frac{1}{2}$, but $P(X_1 > X_0 \: | X_0 = 100) = 0$.

Comment: @LeanderTilstedKristensen  No...I am assuming $X_0$ is chosen uniformly from the given range. That's why I said you get an integral, as you must consider the desired expected number for each possible value of $X_0$.  As I mentioned, this clearly diverges in the discrete case...it diverges in the continuous case as well, but I think that is less obvious.

Comment: Integrating out the expected number for each possible value of $X_0$ is mathematically equivalent to conditioning on $X_0$ and then using the law of total expectation. I do however believe that this is the right way to go, since you cannot assume that the events $\{X_1 > X_0\},\{X_2 > X_0\} \dots$ are independent, but they are however conditionally independent given $X_0$.

Answer (score 1):

Let $N = \min\{ n \geq 1 : X_n > X_0\}$ (it's a random variable).

We want $\mathbb{E}[N]$.

Let's start with something easier, $\mathbb{E}[N|X_0]$. In this case, since $X_0$ is "fixed", we have $N_{|X_0} \sim Geo(1-\frac{X_0}{100})$. Therefore $\mathbb{E}[N|X_0] = \frac{100}{100-X_0}$.

Now $\mathbb{E}[N] = \mathbb{E}[\mathbb{E}[N|X_0]] = \mathbb{E}[\frac{100}{100-X_0}] = +\infty$

Comment: Thanks so much. Why does the Expectation of that fractional value approach infinity? Can't we simplify that to 100/(100-E[X0]) = 100/(100-50) = 2?

Comment: we absolutely can't! $\mathbb{E}$ does not commute with operations!

Comment: We can say it is $\infty$ because it is equal to $\frac{1}{100}\int_0^{100}\frac{100}{100-x}dx = \int_0^{100} \frac{1}{y} dy = +\infty$